# how to compare time with 4:00:AM

Tags: c#

I want run a process on at a specific time (4:00 AM).  Here is my code:

```
if(Current time == 4:00)
{
    ProcessStartInfo autorestart = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\Autostart.bat");
    autorestart.UseShellExecute = false;
    SecureString pw = new SecureString();

    pw.AppendChar('p');
    pw.AppendChar('a');
    pw.AppendChar('s');
    pw.AppendChar('s');
    pw.AppendChar('w');
    pw.AppendChar('o');
    pw.AppendChar('r');
    pw.AppendChar('d');

    autorestart.Password = pw;
    autorestart.UserName = "support";
    Process.Start(autorestart);
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Time not same");
}
```

Comment: Please clarify: does your method run only once?  Or is it looping and waiting until *after* it's 4:00 AM?  Then does it exit after the first time it runs the body of the code (i.e. after 4:00 AM) or does it keep running until tomorrow's 4:00 AM and on and on?  The answers to these questions may or may not require that you store state somewhere so it doesn't execute more than once per day.

Comment: How about `DateTime.Now.ToString("H:mm").Equals("4:00")` ?

Comment: It should be "H:mm". @HariPrasad

Comment: @dotctor true, ahh.. missed it. :-)

Comment: yes doctor i want to perform the restart every day on 4 o clock in the morning

Comment: great Doctor.realy so nice of you it worked.doctor one more question may i asked that my system task.schedule service is getting automaticaly down and i have to start it again through none admin acount.so will you give me any idea for that in c# code pleaseeeeeeeeee